# Show Notes for this Order Comments on sales order grid

Tags: magento2.3, magento2.3.4, order-grid

Trying to show order comments on sales order grid. I have the column but can't seem to show the data. I can show data with eg city or phone number but not the order comments.

Comments.php

```
namespace Fitzcode\AdminEdits\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

class Comment extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;

    public function __construct(ContextInterface $context, UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria, array $components = [], array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $comment = $order->getStatusComment();
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $comment;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

sales_order_grid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="telephone" class="Fitzcode\AdminEdits\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Telephone">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Phone Number</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="comment" class="Fitzcode\AdminEdits\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Comment">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Comment</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">7</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

[image: Order Notes/Comments]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/325276/show-admin-order-comments-in-sales-order-grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code with $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);

```
            $statusHistoryItem = $order->getStatusHistoryCollection()->getFirstItem();
            $status = $statusHistoryItem->getStatusLabel();
            $comment = $statusHistoryItem->getComment();
            //exit;
            $item[$this->getData('name')] = $comment;
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try printing $dataSource before returning with exit()? Check if $dataSource actually contains the comments data.

```
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {

                $order  = $this->_orderRepository->get($item["entity_id"]);
                $comment = $order->getStatusComment();
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = $comment;
            }
        }
        echo "<pre>";print_r($dataSource);exit;
        return $dataSource;
    }
```

Comment: Not quite sure how to do that sorry I'm an amateur. If I change the following line it returns the customers telephone. ```$comment = $order->getStatusComment();``` To ```$comment = $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();```

Comment: try this before returning $dataSource and see what it returns to the grid. 
`echo"<pre>";print_r($dataSource);exit;`

Comment: It returns nothing to the grid.

Comment: I'd suggest you to print $order and $comment as well and check if they are returning what you want. If yes, then just put your grid field name in $item like `$item['field_name'] = $comment` insted of `$this->getData('name')` and see if it works.

Comment: I don't think I am placing the ```echo"<pre>";print_r($dataSource);exit;``` In the right place are you able to paste the whole code with the changes. Sorry and thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer. If `$dataSource` doesn't contain your comments then try printing `$order`and `$comments` as I mentioned in above comment.

Comment: ```$dataSource``` Returns nothing in the comments ```$order``` and ```$comment``` return a blank page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115562/discussion-between-abdulsamadabbasi-and-shaun).