# Show admin order comments in sales order grid

Tags: magento2, sales-order, magento2.3.4, order-grid

I am trying to show admin order comments in a new column I created in sales order grid. Anyone know how I would do this?

[image: Admin Order Comments]

Comment: For a single order multiple comment will be there. which comment are you show in order grid?

Comment: The most recent comment would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

[This link will help you to solve your issue ] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5fc0rsCrdw

Answer (score 0):

**

### Create File At: Vendor\Module\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sales_order_grid.xml

**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">
                    Vendor_Module/js/grid/listing
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <column name="letestcomment" class="Dolphin\Ordercomment\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Letestcomment">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">
                        ui/grid/cells/html
                    </item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">
                        true
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">
                        Letest Comment
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**

### Than Create Another File At: Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Letestcomment.php

**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Status\History\CollectionFactory;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;

class Letestcomment extends Column
{
    protected $historyCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        CollectionFactory $historyCollectionFactory,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->historyCollectionFactory = $historyCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$items) {
                $history = $this->historyCollectionFactory->create();
                $history->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $items["entity_id"]);

                //uncomment code as your requirements to set filter
                // $history->addFieldToFilter('comment', array('neq' => 'NULL'));
                // $history->addFieldToFilter('entity_name', 'order');
                // $history->setOrder('created_at', 'DESC');
                $comment = $history->getFirstItem()->getComment();
                $items['letestcomment'] = $comment;
            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Uncomment created_at DESC Filter If You Want Most Recent Comment.
&
Run command php -f bin/magento setup:upgrade.

And Done :)